# Count data displayed on my datagridview with category

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am having a trouble on counting datas on my datagridview using category i.e. when i filtered my datas by "Department" it shows all data on the same category. But i want to count how many Staffs, Supervisors and Managers are included on that category (Department). I want it to be displayed on my textboxes i.e. txtStaff, tstManagers, txtSups. Thanks you!

Here's my current code :

```
    Try
    Dim conF As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.; Data Source = ..\Database\IRMG TO.accdb")
    conF.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT Employee_Name, P_Level, Position_Title, Department, Team, Subteam1, Subteam2, Immediate_Head, CAREER_BAND, CAREER_ZONE FROM tblEmployees WHERE (" & txtFilterType.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%') "
        Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conF)
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    dgvEmployee.DataSource = dt
    adapter.Dispose()
    command.Dispose()
        conF.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do this SQL statement...

```
query = "SELECT (Select COUNT(Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Position_Title='Staff' AND (" & txtFilterType.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%')) as StaffCount,
        (Select COUNT(Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Position_Title='Supervisor' AND (" & txtFilterType.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%')) as SupervisorCount,
        (Select COUNT(Employee_Name) FROM tblEmployees WHERE Position_Title='Manager' AND (" & txtFilterType.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%')) as ManagerCount,
         Employee_Name, P_Level, Position_Title, Department, Team, Subteam1, Subteam2, Immediate_Head, CAREER_BAND, CAREER_ZONE FROM tblEmployees WHERE (" & txtFilterType.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%')"
```

Then you VB should go something like this...

```
  adapter.Fill(dt)
  txtStaff.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("StaffCount") 
  txtSups.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SupervisorCount") 
  tstManagers.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ManagerCount")
```

Don't forget to hide the first 3 columns of your datagridview after it's filled up. You're using the datasource property so everything will come out, just hide them. You'll have more control over your datagridview before it's filled up if you do the loop to display the items than using the datasource directly.

Comment: Hi, i mean, it is not the row that i want to count, It's the data inside my datatable. i.e. I filtered my table by Department, then Department contains data such as name of supervisors, managers and staff. I want to count how many staffs, managers and supervisors are there and insert the datas into three textboxes. i.e. txtStaffCount, txtManagersCount and txtSupervisorsCount

Comment: So when you filter out data, all the fields, supervisors, managers, staff appear right? And let's say you select a certain department, there are 3 rows that appear, and only supervisors have values, so that does that supervisors=3, managers=0, staff=0? Did I get your question right?

Comment: Yes it's like that, and when i select a certain department that has 5 rows and consist of 3 supervisors and 2 staffs i want to display a count for supervisors and staffs into their respective textboxes. :)

Comment: Check my edited answer. If it does answer your question, please don't forget to mark it as answered by checking the answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, do i need to replace my sql statement with yours? or do i need to make a new one? thanks

Comment: Replace your SQL statement with the one I provided :)

Comment: Hi Chris, It sums how many staffs, managers, and sups in my DB. :( , it disregards my filtered data which is Department.

Comment: Check my edited code. I forgot to add the additional condition :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.. :

```
txtResult.Text = dgvEmployee.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Hi, i mean, it is not the row that i want to count, It's the data inside my datatable. i.e. I filtered my table by Department, then Department contains data such as name of supervisors, managers and staff. I want to count how many staffs, managers and supervisors are there and insert the datas into three textboxes. i.e. txtStaffCount, txtManagersCount and txtSupervisorsCount